# Angular 5 Two way bind an interfaced to <select>

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have settings interface that I load from the back end and I want to bind it to a select box. I'm kind of lost right now how I would do it.

My select box looks like this right now.

```
   <select class="custom-select" 
    [(ngModel)]="setting[0].isPrivate">
      <option [value]="Y">Yes</option>
      <option [value]="N">No</option>
    </select>

   <select class="custom-select" 
    [(ngModel)]="setting[0].hideEmail">
      <option [value]="Y">Yes</option>
      <option [value]="N">No</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Comment: The select box value after loading is blank.